# On use of parenthesis

Tags: basic

So I was looking over some A-Levels Computer Science past papers, and stumbled into this:

[image]

Now, my first reaction was that there is no need for parenthesis on line 6. Reason being that algebraic operators take precedence over comparisons which take precedence over boolean ones.

As a small example from Java:

```
        int a = 100;
        int b = 100;
        int c = 100;
        int d = 100;

        if( ((c+d) > 180) && ((a+b+c+d)) >= 320)
            System.out.println("greater");

        if(c+d > 180 && a+b+c+d >=320)
            System.out.println("greateragain");
```

Both if statements are evaluated to true.

So, am I right in thinking parenthesis are only for human readability in this case or...?

Comment: Well it depends on the semantics of the language in that first snippet (which definitely isn't Java...)

Comment: If the language in question has comparison operators at a higher precedence than the addition operator, then the parenthesis are needed so it doesn't evaluate to `c + (d >= 180)`. But like it's being said, this is not java so hard to know..

Comment: Totally depends on the language used. If your assumption was correct and this was java then yes there is no need for paranthesis but clearly this is not java. It looks more like GW Basic (not sure though did it a long time ago).

Comment: operator precedence depends on the language syntax. When in doubt, you put the parentheses. That's why they're here.

Comment: Agree that it totally depends on the language, but I would suggest that writing any code in a particular way to make it more readable is a very important consideration. Especially with someone not familiar with the language, they could still read that code and know exactly what it's doing.

Comment: As far as I know A-level computer science uses C++, now they switched to Python. Never heard them using Java.

Comment: Looks like [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) to me - added tag in the hope that someone will recognise the dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say: *"The use of parentheses makes the precendence of evaluation explicit, disregarding of the operator precendence of the language in use."*

The comments above describe well that operator precendence is language specific. For example, in Pascal, logical operators such as AND seem to have higher precendence than math operators, and interpreted as binary AND. In contrast in C, the && has lower precedence, hence you can save some parentheses.

Therefore, it sounds like a wise idea to *always* use parentheses in case of a possible ambiguity, or at least until you're mastering the language in use.

Answer (score 2):

[BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) was one of the early languages that took advantage of the fact that logical operators and bit-wise operators can share the same mnemonic.

In the example - `c+d > 180 AND a+b+c+d >= 320` **could** (*by a stretch of the imagination*) have been interpreted as `(c + d) > (180 AND a) + b + c + (d > 320)`.  For this reason it is necessary to add brackets to eremove all ambiguity.